# The word 'Kuchen'. Alternate meaning or misheard?

Tags: meaning, translation, word-choice, listening-comprehension

I have heard native German speaker use the word '**Kuchen**' to mean to call back/discuss.

For example: Kuchen sie mit Hr.xyz

I cant find this any other meaning for this word apart from cake.

Is there some other similar sounding word? or have I just misheard **rufen**?

Comment: The closest I can think of is _"ver**suchen** sie's mit Hr xyz"_. I am afraid this question isn't concisely answerable here without more context.

Comment: _"or have I just misheard **rufen**?"_ _rufen mit_ doesn't make sense.

Comment: And BTW, it's almost sure you misheard something, there's no alternate meaning of _Kuchen_ than _cake_.

Comment: Maybe "Kochen sie mit ..." ? (cook with...)

Comment: I‘d guess „kucken“ as „look“....

Answer (score 3):

There is no other meaning for "Kuchen" than "cake" in German. I am almost certain you misheard something. As you suggest that "call back/discuss" was meant, some things that come to mind could be:

- anrufen -> call/call back
- suchen -> search
- aufsuchen -> see/call/visit, and (as was already suggested)
- versuchen -> try

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you heard the word [kuschen [ˈkʊʃn̩]](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/kuschen), not Kuchen [ˈkuːxn̩].

It means "to knuckle under" and would usually used with "vor", not with "mit". For example:

> Kuschen Sie vor Herrn XYZ!

Comment: "*to mean to call back/discuss.*" - 'kuschen' doesn't really fit the given context, imho

Comment: Really smashing joke! How about '_Kuscheln Sie mit Herrn XYZ_'?

Comment: Well, "call back" might be a misinterpretation – the relationship might be more subordinate than Adithya perceived.